# Mac clean and start a fresh install with out losing Mavericks operating system

Tags: mac, osx-mavericks

I've recently upgraded to Mavericks from Snow Leopard on my Mac Pro.

I would like to now re-install the system so my Mac is completely fresh, with no apps or any data. Basically factory reset.

But I can't find my mac installer discs and I don't want to have to re-download mavericks installer again.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do a network recovery as detailed here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718

Comment: Interesting indeed, but I doubt this will lessen the data volume needed to reinstall the system.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, bad skim-reading. If you want access to the Mavericks installer _after_ using it, you need to move it to a location other than Applications prior to running it, otherwise it is deleted. Not that this information is of any use to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting to the restoration partition that Mavericks creates on install? Reboot, holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> then select the restore partition. Run Disk Utility. Wipe the OS partition, then install Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

To do that I think you will need to download 10.9 and create a CD or flash drive to boot from. Than you will need to use disk utility to wipe the disk and install. I use an app called Disk Maker X to create a bootable flash drive. http://liondiskmaker.com/